Why can't I set a bounty for my own question
Recently I wrote this question and I've had a couple of interesting answers but it's all gone a bit quiet. I'd like to offer up some reputation as a bounty to encourage more activity but I'm not getting the link. Another question that I asked is offering the link so I'm wondering what the rules are?

I believe that you have to wait for two days (after asking the question) before you can start a bounty.

Correct.  Stack exchange will even indicate this where the bountry button would be saying "you must wait 2 days to place a bounty".
